# How to access mongodb with one command

Tags: mongodb

Today, when I have to use my mongodb,

1. I first use mongod to define my mondodb path
2. Then I use mongo to start the instance
3. Then I use mongoose to connect

I remember Hibernate does all these in one shot. How can I do all these three tasks in MongoDB in just one command?

Comment: Using *Hibernate* or any other *ORM* is like your third step when you were using MongoDB, i.e. using mongoose. When you're using hibernate, you should already have a Relational database instance up and running like postgresql. Running a relational database is like what you did in the first step.

Comment: And also, you are wrong about the second step. `mongo` is interactive client for connecting to a `mongod` instance. You did not run the mongo database using mongo client.  `mongo` for mongodb is something like `psql` for PostgreSQL

Comment: The bottom line is Hibernate **Does Not** all of those steps in one shot. You still need to run a relational database (Step 1) and then use hibernate to connect to it (Step 3)

Comment: Are you suggesting that running mongod --dbpath "path/goes/here" should get the server started. I do not need a mongo interactive client open? I tried that, it didn't work. I never had to get my SQLYog kept open when I am using my application with MySQL.

Comment: @AliDehghani, I guess I will have to open the client through the application and not from my local machine